# When splitting a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In this code below, it is supposed to take a number and reverse it

I tried to do it without `num = num + ""` but it does not work

why do I need to add that before I split the number ?

```
function reverseANumber(num) {

    function reverse() {

        num = num + "";
        var newNum;
        newNum = num.split("").reverse().join();
        return newNum;
    }
    return reverse(num);
}

console.log(reverseANumber(34521));
```

Comment: Because `.split` is a method of `String.prototype`

Comment: your function should really just be `return isNaN(n) ? null : String(n).split("").reverse().join();` no need for the extra function and whatnot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the line

```
num = num + "";
```

`num` is actually a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), and doesn't have a [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.  Once you've made `num` into a string (by concatenating it with an empty string), it has the `.split` function and things work out.  (A clearer method is `num.toString()`)

You've got another bug in your code: [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will join the elements of an array with either the arguments you've provided or, if none are given, commas.  (i.e. `[1,2,3]` => `'1,2,3'`).  You need to provide `.join` with an empty string for this function (and parseInt/parseFloat) to work properly.

It's worth noting that your function doesn't actually return a *number*, but rather a string that looks like a number.  This may cause problems down the line.  You can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get the variable back in Number form.

Cleaned up a bit (the function `reverse` is a bit superfluous), your function becomes:

```
function reverseANumber(num) {
  var numAsString = num.toString();
  var reversedNumAsString = numAsString.split('').reverse().join('');
  return parseFloat(reversedNumAsString, 10);
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried parseInt and it is only parsing the first number and outputting 1, why is that ? it is also returning:1,2,5,4,3 not 12543 when I do not parse it to an integer

Answer (score 0):

variable num is probably an integer with + "" you parse it to string.

if you want to skip + "", then you have to pass a string to that function, like so:

```
var num = "35";// instead of 35
reverse(num);
```

Comment: reverse doesn't work with strings, you use it arrays.

Comment: reverse is his defined function

Answer (score 0):

Because `num` is a number. For splitting you need convert number to string. So that is why you use `num + ""` before call method `split`

Answer (score 0):

[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string in order to make it array, then use [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reverse)

```
function reverse(myNum){
myNum= myNum.split("").reverse().join("");
return myNum;
}

console.log(reverse("34521"));
```

---

Output:

```
12543
```

---

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/rVBGWM)